# Are there any consumer style websites that offer WebDav support?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, iwork

iWork for iPad now has WebDav export/import options, DropBox doesn't support WebDav.

Where can I find a service that has WebDav support? Besides setting up my own server, is there any consumer (and ideally free) site that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Box.NET](https://www.box.net/). It has WebDav access (among other things)

([Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/5196/whats-the-best-free-webdav-service-out-there/5986#5986)).

Answer (score 1):

The Omni Group Forum thread, [List of free webDAV sync providers](http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=11054), has links to a number of  possibilities.